# Is it possible to open an application already downloaded with web browser (like Safari for iPad)?

Tags: php, javascript, iphone, ipad, safari

I would like open an application when a user enter an URL in Safari.

For example :

twitter.com open twitter application.

Is it possible in web programming language : JavaScript, PHP ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to open an application on the iPhone from Safari. you'll have to register a custom URL Scheme in your applications Project Settings. Then in your web application you can create a link to your custom url scheme that will open the application.

For example if you were using twitter as the url scheme you could have the web application redirect to to the url twitter://

One issue though is that if the application isn't on the device then the redirect will fail.

Comment: Ahh, I figured he wanted to use a computer, not an iPhone. In that case, then yes I suppose it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to open downloaded application from web-browser on iOS-based device then you should compose a link with [custom url scheme](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html).

You find a lot of url scheme examples on this site - [AKOSMA IPhone URL Schemes](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes)

Answer (score 0):

No, that would be something your browser would have to do. Or you could just do it manually.